# How to create a Web Api OData feed that can be consumed by Excel

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created a simple OData enabled Web Api. Now I want to use this feed from Excel, which seems to require a .svc file of a certain format (that describes the available resources).

Is there something in the ASP.NET Web Api OData library that helps here or do I need to create this myself?

Can any one point me to a example of a Web API OData feed that Excel can consume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Connect to an OData feed from Excel**

1. In the **POWER QUERY** ribbon tab, click **From Other Source** > **From OData**
   Feed.
2. In the **OData Feed** dialog box, enter the **URL** for an OData feed.
3. Click **OK**.
4. If the OData feed requires user credentials, in the **Access an OData feed** dialog box:

   - Click **Basic** if the OData feed requires your username and password.
   - Click **Feed Key** if the OData feed requires an account key. You can click the Get your Marketplace Account Key to subscribe to Windows Azure marketplace OData feeds. You can also Sign up for Windows Azure Marketplace from the Access an OData Feed dialog box.
   - Click **Microsoft Online Service ID** if the OData feed requires federated access credentials. For Windows Live ID, log into your account.
   - Click **Save**.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-an-odata-feed-HA104019824.aspx